# PHP site developed using Laravel 5 is not getting rendered after Hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5

I developed a php site using Laravel 5 and tried hosting it in a LAN Server running UBUNTU 14. But when I navigated the page I'm just getting a Blank Page. No errors at all. I inserted a simple echo statement in index.php and I got the relevant echo.

Comment: In config/app.php change `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG'),` to `'debug' => true,` and that should enable errors.

Comment: Are you by any chance using Laravel 5.1? The minimum requirement is PHP 5.5.9. Not sure about the PHP version of Ubuntu 14, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: did you run composer install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many reason. If you are using Laravel 5.0, you will need at least PHP 5.4. For Laravel 5.1, you will need 5.5.9. But if you have installed PHP using `sudo apt-get install php5` you are most likely to have PHP 5.5.9 or later. Because that is the default version for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. try running `php -v` from terminal to check the version.

There can also be a Permission issue for `storage` folder.
From project root folder run following command,

```
sudo chmod 755 -R storage
```

Basically, laravel needs write access to storage folder to write a log in `storage/log` directory or to write a compiled view files in `storage/framework/views` etc. You can try 755 first. If that does not work try 777.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel shows nothing on certain fatal errors. For instance a class that can't be found or the storage directory and subdirectories that should be writable for the web user (www-data). This should show up in the error log of the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have permissions issue chmod 755 storage folder located in the root of your web project. If that doesn't works do it 777.

The reason why echo in the index.php is working is because this is the first file called when you execute the laravel app and the index file calls services provider and other required files, in this process the app creates a cache file under storage/framework/views/ folder but these files does not have write permissions, but as you echo something you get that output because it has been called even before anything was called.