# No error show blank page

Tags: laravel-5

After uploading Laravel 5.0 on server, it does not show any error. It is only showing a blank page. Debug is set to true. Please help me.

I have php5.4 version using hostgator hosting.

Answer (score 0):

do following

```
 sudo chmod 755 -R storage
```

if `755` does not work try `777`

**UPDATE**

already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006085/php-site-developed-using-laravel-5-is-not-getting-rendered-after-hosting/31008648#31008648)

```
sudo chmod -R ug+rw storage
```

Permissions will be like 664 or 775

Comment: it does not work.   i did it  but into the storage folder all file is 755.

Comment: there is a an option on the left side of my answer.